# Adding extra fields to a timetable

Tags: tables

I need to mention the input and output work product of each step in my timetable.

The current template provides me something like this:

[image]

I need to have some extra fields before and after the task to add input and output work products like this:

[image]

Here is the corresponding `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[•]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}
\usepackage
[
        letterpaper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        left=2cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=3cm,
        bottom=4cm,
        vmargin=2cm,
        % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
        % us  hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
        % use margin=3cm to make all margins  equal to 3cm.
]
{geometry}
%for timetable
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\ytl[2]{
    \parbox[b]{8em}{\hfill{\color{cyan}\bfseries\sffamily #1}~$\cdots\cdots$~}\makebox[0pt][c]{$\bullet$}\vrule\quad \parbox[c]{7.5cm}{\vspace{7pt}\color{red!40!black!80}\raggedright\sffamily #2.\\[7pt]}\\[-3pt]}
%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{My timetable}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.7\linewidth}
        \color{gray}
        \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
        \ytl{1947}{Composing the thesis draft}
        \ytl{1968}{Reviewing the thesis draft by the supervisor}
        \ytl{1971}{Analyzing and applying the supervisor's comments}
        \ytl{1973}{Sending the thesis to the referees}
        \ytl{1978}{Preparing presentation slides}
        \ytl{1968}{Reviewing the presentation slides by the supervisor}
        \ytl{1971}{Analyzing and applying the supervisor's comments}
        \ytl{1981}{Defense}
        \bigskip
        \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}%
    \end{minipage}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**How can I edit `\ytl` command to reflect the desired format?**

Comment: What is `\documentclass[•]{article}` supposed to do, i.e. the dot?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Nothing special!... It was just a part of the primary template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}
\usepackage
[
        letterpaper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        left=2cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=3cm,
        bottom=4cm,
        vmargin=2cm,
        % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
        % us  hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
        % use margin=3cm to make all margins  equal to 3cm.
]
{geometry}
%for timetable
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\ytlformat}{\color{red!40!black!80}\sffamily}
\newcommand\ytl[4]{%
    \color{cyan}\bfseries\sffamily #1%
    & \ytlformat #2
    & \ytlformat #3
    & \ytlformat #4
    \\[7pt]
}
%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{My timetable}
    \smallskip
    \begin{tabular}{l !{~$\cdots\cdots$~\makebox[0pt][l]{$\bullet$}}| lll}%
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \ytlformat input & \ytlformat task & \ytlformat output \\
        \midrule
        \addlinespace[0pt]%
        \rule{0pt}{1.8em}%
        \ytl{1947}{draft}{revery}{comments}
        \ytl{1948}{draft}{revery}{comments}
        \ytl{1949}{draft}{revery}{comments}
        \ytl{1950}{draft}{revery}{comments}
        \addlinespace[0pt]%
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

"Also, `\addlinespace` can be used before, after, or between rules if you want to control the exact amount of  space  to  be  inserted." ([booktabs documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) page 5)
`\addlinespace[0pt]` is necessary to avoid a gap between the rules.